# Why doesn’t type() always return the real class in Python?

Tags: python, class, types

In Python, the [built-in function `type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) always returns the *real* class of an instance, except if the instance variable `__class__` has been set ***and* the class variable `__class__` has *not* been set**, in which case it returns the instance variable `__class__`. What is the rationale for this exception?

```py
class X:
    pass

class A:
    __class__ = X

a = A()
print(type(a))      # prints <class '__main__.A'> (the real class)
print(a.__class__)  # prints <class '__main__.X'>
```

```py
class X:
    pass

class Y:
    pass

class A:
    __class__ = X

a = A()
a.__class__ = Y
print(type(a))      # prints <class '__main__.A'> (the real class)
print(a.__class__)  # prints <class '__main__.Y'>
```

```py
class X:
    pass

class A:
    pass

a = A()
a.__class__ = X
print(type(a))      # prints <class '__main__.X'> (NOT the real class)
print(a.__class__)  # prints <class '__main__.X'>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`type` *does* always return the real class. When you did

```py
class X:
    pass

class A:
    pass

a = A()
a.__class__ = X
```

you *changed the class* of `a`. The default `__class__` [data descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors), `object.__dict__['__class__']`, is tied to the actual class of an object, and setting `__class__` changes the actual class.

You'll find that, for example, `a` now has the methods of an `X` instance instead of an `A` instance (except that you didn't write any methods).

On the other hand, when you did

```py
class X:
    pass

class Y:
    pass

class A:
    __class__ = X

a = A()
a.__class__ = Y
```

you hid the default `__class__` descriptor. Now the `a.__class__` assignment doesn't find a descriptor, so it just sets a `'__class__'` entry in the instance dict instead of changing the instance's class.

Comment: Thanks, you nailed it! I did not know that the `__class__` attribute of `object` was a *data descriptor*, and that applying its `__set__` method on an instance was the only way to update the *real* class of  that instance, i.e. the class returned by the `type` built-in function applied on that instance. That makes perfect sense now.